# How to use pseudo-class for changing background color of selected items in multiple select list

Tags: css, html-select, pseudo-element

I have a multiple select list. I am trying to get anything selected to have a background color and anything selected to not have one.

form > filed > select > option
I called form id=opti
I tried

```
#opti option:focus {
    background-color: #ffd56f;
}
#opti option:active {
    background-color: #ffd56f;
}
#opti option:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

the hover works, but im interested in changing the selected option elements background color when selected, not only when hovered.

If there is not an option for this in css, what is a good alternative (not giving me a link to a premade 3rd party software), perhaps javascript function that runs when an item selection is changed, or when one is selected and one selected.

Any help would be great

Comment: i tried :checked it did not work. I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:checked` pseudo-class. ([More information about the :checked pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked))

But browsers and operating systems often treat the select/option-elements individually and don't allow some or all of the styling.

For example on Firefox (macOS) the `background-color` from styling gets ignored. But you can utilize `box-shadow` to change the color of the background.

But to have fully customized select-elements in your page, that are looking and behaving on all browsers the same, you also can use a replacement-library like [Select2](https://select2.org/).

```css
select option:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
select option:checked {
  background-color: red; /* NOT working on Firefox (macOS) */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px orange inset; /* working on Firefox (macOS) */
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="1">Lorem</option>
  <option value="2">Ipsum</option>
  <option value="3">Stack</option>
  <option value="4">Overflow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px orange inset; /* working on Firefox (macOS) */ made the difference in chrome! thanks

Comment: just having one more use. using color:red; or font-weight:bold; does not change the checked items text color and weight. do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: -webkit-text-fill-color: red;